# Still an observer pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Usually when I see tutorials about Observer Pattern I see an unique method called `notify`, but I'm wondering. What if I have different methods that can be called in different moments but needs to notify the others when this happen? Like events, am I doing this wrong? or still begin the observer pattern?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Observer
{
public:
    virtual void notifyBefore() = 0;
    virtual void notifyAfter() = 0;
};

class Subject
{
public:
    void attachObserver(Observer * observer)
    {
        observers.push_back(observer);
    }

    void detachObserver(Observer * observer)
    {
        auto index = std::find(observers.begin(), observers.end(), observer);
        if (index != observers.end())
        {
            observers.erase(index);
        }
    }

    virtual void notifyBefore()
    {
        for (auto current : observers)
        {
            current->notifyBefore();
        }
    }

    virtual void notifyAfter()
    {
        for (auto current : observers)
        {
            current->notifyAfter();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Observer *> observers;
};

class ConcreteObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    void notifyBefore()
    {
        std::cout << "You called me before..." << std::endl;
    }

    void notifyAfter()
    {
        std::cout << "You called me after..." << std::endl;
    }
};

class ConcreteSubject : public Subject
{
public:

};

int main()
{
    auto subject = new ConcreteSubject;
    subject->attachObserver(new ConcreteObserver);

    subject->notifyBefore();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    subject->notifyAfter();
}
```

Comment: In my opinion it's still an implementation of the Observer pattern.   Seems like a pretty straight-forward example of an Observer to me

Comment: The names of the methods are unimportant. it is the "pattern" that matters ie. the arrangement of objects and the class structure.

Comment: What do you think makes you question it is not observer pattern? :) The binding is there, the pattern is there!

Comment: The reason I haven't see anything like that in the internet about the pattern, then I thought it might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Is it still an observer pattern? sure

Answer (score 1):

You created an observer pattern with 2 types of events/notifications.

You could have written it as:

```
void notify(Type type);
```

Where Type is the type of event (e.g. an enum).

You can also pass other parameters to indicate other parameters relevant to the event.

```
void notify(Type type, std::string value);
```

Comment: Like a strategy pattern? It might help.